# How to turn PHP variables into XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to do some feed submission for MWS.

I have a db that I need to make a call from.

dbCall functiion and $sql is the sql that calls the variable from customer database.

```
$var =  dbCall($sql);
for ($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++ )
{
feed[] = "<Message>
            <MessageID>".$messageID."</MessageID>
                    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                    <Product>
                        <SKU>book_".$var[$x]."</SKU>
                        <StandardProductID>
                            <Type>ASIN</Type>
                            <Value>".$var[$x]."</Value>
                        </StandardProductID>
                        <Condition>
                            <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                            <ConditionNote>Brand New! Never used!</ConditionNote>
                        </Condition>
                    </Product>
                </Message>";


            $messageID = $messageID + 1;


            }

            $total_feed =  implode(" ", $feed);

            $final_feed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
                <Header>
                    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                    <MerchantIdentifier>'.$merch_id.'</MerchantIdentifier>
                </Header>
                <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
                <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>' .$total_feed.'</AmazonEnvelope>');
```

`

When I run this; I get the string back but some of the tags don't align properly (see SKU and value).

[image: results]

How do I get an XML output from database variables?

Edit: 
When I print the output for implode(" ",$feed) - all my tags seem lower case, but if I use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities, I get them in correct format.

```
<message> instead of <Message>
```

Comment: you could try `trim($var[$x])`

Comment: @RamRaider thanks, I think that worked, but ...how do I know if this is really XML? I currently am only able to see it formated when I put htmlentities() infront of it?
edit: trim works now. Tahnks ram!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using trim adjusted the xml correctly.